# Estimating the scale parameter in a weibull dist using proportional hazard parameterization

Tags: stata, survival-analysis, weibull

According to https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2014-02/msg00188.html, I have to define

b = _b[_cons]

But I do not know exactly what that means or how to do it?

Comment: This was answered in the post you cite. After `streg`  you can access `_b[_cons]` and assign to a scalar with e.g. `scalar b = _b[_cons]`. If this isn't the answer, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think I got it now sir - thank you very much for your response

Comment: Try adding this as an answer, to help others!